# Writing to an already existing file using FileWriter Java

Tags: java, io, filewriter

Is there anyway I can write to an already existing file using Filewriter

For example when the user clicks a submit button:

```
FileWriter writer = new FileWriter("myfile.csv");
writer.append("LastName");
writer.append(',');
writer.append("FirstName");
writer.append('/n');

writer.append(LastNameTextField.getText());
writer.append(',');
writer.append(FirstNameTextField.getText());
```

I want to be able to write new data into the already existing myfile.csv without having to recreate a brand new one every time

Comment: Do you want to append (write the new data at the end of the old), or replace (write the new data over the top of the old)?  I would have thought append (as did the answerers so far), but "write new data into" sounds more like replace.

Answer (score 23):

Yeah. Use the constructor like this:

```
FileWriter writer = new FileWriter("myfile.csv",true);
```

Comment: @TwilightPonyInc. It's not quite pseudocode, it is the method declaration, but yeah! The code is ALWAYS much more useful!

Answer (score 7):

```
FileWriter

public FileWriter(File file,
                  boolean append)
           throws IOException

Constructs a FileWriter object given a File object. If the second argument is true, then bytes will be written to the end of the file rather than the beginning.
```